# How to get IntelliJ to recognize imports in Scala script?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, ammonite

I'm having trouble getting IntelliJ to recognize Ammonite imports in my Scala script. This is a new feature, reported [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/11/28/intellij-idea-scala-plugin-2017-3-lightbend-project-starter-ammonite-support-parallel-indexing-and-more/), where there are also instructions. I followed the instructions and I started a new sbt project in IntelliJ to try it out, but it's not working.

I see the Ammonite dependencies in the project's "External Libraries", which I specified in the `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "ammonite-ops" % "1.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % "1.0.3" cross CrossVersion.full`

The (quite simple) project seems to successfully build. I also specified that Scala worksheet files should be treated as "Always Ammonite".

All this, yet the IDE shows the script like:
[image]

What more do I need to do to get this to work?

Versions:

- Java 1.8.0
- Scala 2.12.4
- sbt 1.0.3
- IntelliJ CE 2017.3.2
- IntelliJ scala plugin 2017.3.11

Comment: One thing I noticed is that transitive dependencies are not pulled into scope unfortunately. For example if I pull in `circe` library and have IntelliJ download that, I'm still not able to resolve import for `cats` library (which `circe` depends on)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar issues with IntelliJ, so let me share how I made it work.

My versions:

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.3.2 (so basically the same version as yours)
- IntelliJ Scala plugin 2017.3.11
- Kubuntu, so keyboard shortcuts below may have to be adjusted

Now, I started from the same code as you have, **with updated version of dependency `0.6.7`**. 
[image: Staring code]

Already now pressing the green arrow to next to 1st line runs Ammonite. The dependencies are downloaded and link is displayed. **That is mandatory step** for IntelliJ to recognize that new jar is available.

Also at this stage Intellij shows me a small popup with information that I can import the jar. **I did not use it**.
[image: Import $ivy dependencies]

To make IntelliJ recognize the imports, I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> *Show Intention Actions* on the broken `com.lihaoyi::scalatags:0.6.7` dependency and use **Create library from jar...**
[image: Create library from jar...]

This makes Intellij recognize the library, imports and it can start giving you hints.
[image]

The library is added to the Project's dependencies (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>). You can see also dependencies coming from other files below.
[image: Project structure with added dependency]

Comment: You forgot to mention changing form 0.6.0 to 0.6.7 :) That version was missing from the Maven repo. Also you need to run the script first to get `amm` to download the `pom`s before it will create the lib from jar. Seems like this is not the way the plugin is meant to work, but hey, it's working!

Comment: Thanks @einnocent, I updated the answer with your feedback for future generations.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with IntelliJ and seem to be figthing bugs in IntelliJ.

**My versions:**

- IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.4
- IntelliJ Scala plugin 2018.2.11
- OS: Windows
- Scala: 2.12.6 (at the moment Ammonite current release 1.2.1 is not released for Scala 2.12.7, see [#879](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/879) and below)

**Without IntelliJ Project**

If I just open the .sc file without open project then I get prompted with

- Project JDK is not defined
- No Scala SDK in module
- the notification: 'Add all Ammonite standard dependencies to the project?'

The notification quickly dissapears. If I click 'Add' button before fixing the JDK, the imports does not work, and the add button is gone. fix the jdk and scala, and then find the 'Add all Ammonite...' in the eventlog and click 'add' there, then it works.

However all changes in settings are lost next time I reopen IntelliJ.

**With IntelliJ Project**

- Create new project Scala sbt project, default directory based project.
- I place my sc-files in there somewhere

Now IntelliJ remembers settings for sc-files. I can even open sc files directly from explorer/total commander in IntelliJ after configuring 'open with...' to intellij, though I prefer.

Do NOT allow IntelliJ to auto-import sbt project settings via notification, it seems to ruin the library imports, and I need to recreate project to recover.

**Scala Version issues**

The library auto-import 'add' button will only work for Scala versions for which Ammonite is released. See [Maven Central Ammonite releases](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lihaoyi/ammonite-interp). At the time of writing Ammonite 1.2.1 is not released for scala-2.12.7, though the current unstable version of ammonite is. See [Ammonite bug-report #879](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/879). The add button just fails silently, which sucks, esp. for a newbie like me.

The auto-generated sbt build file looks like this

```
name := "Ammonite"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

This is how it looks in project settings after libraries have successfully loaded:

[image]

and here are the dependencies that make it compile. Note that the 'SBT : ' dependencies are those auto-generated via SBT-file (it seems), and the others are libraries added by scala plugin ammonite notifications feature

[image]

The above library list is empty when IntelliJ fails to load the ammonite libraries.

**IntelliJ with SBT (because IntelliJ loses ammonite imports, and for $ivy)**

IntelliJ seems to frequently for lose its ammonite imports. If I have SBT setup to give the imports, then it does not matter so much. Also IntelliJ $ivy support for ammonite only works when files are already cached locally in ivy-cache, and running Ammonite script on my windows caches files in different location, which means IntelliJ $ivy imports effectively does not work. Hence I use SBT to setup the sum of the imports I use in my scripts.

My build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lihaoyi/ammonite
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" % ("ammonite_" + scalaVersion) % "1.2.1-16-48ce533"

// Extra example dependency
libraryDependencies += "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.3"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think IntelliJ IDEA won't find a dependency in a local cache if you're working mostly with Scala 2.13 and SBT 1.3+ with the Coursier library management. We need to help IntelliJ IDEA by downloading dependencies to the Ivy cache.

I solved this issue by:

1. Creating the `ivy.xml` somewhere with required dependencies, e.g:

   ```xml
   <ivy-module version="1.0">
       <info organisation="test" module="download-deps"/>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency org="com.softwaremill.sttp.client" name="core_2.12" rev="2.1.1"/>
           <dependency org="com.softwaremill.sttp.client" name="okhttp-backend_2.12" rev="2.1.1"/>
           <dependency org="com.github.tototoshi" name="scala-csv_2.12" rev="1.3.6"/>
       </dependencies>
   </ivy-module>
   ```

   **Note**, I specified Scala 2.12 here.
2. Running `ivy -refresh` from the directory with the created `ivy.xml`.
3. Then we need is to "Create library from jar..." from the red import's context actions in IntelliJ IDEA.

That's all!

Comment: This worked for me when I opened my worksheet directory alone, not within my Mill project.

Answer (score -1):

you need to associate .sc files with ammonite.

in you settings, it should look like this
[image]
(solution taken from [here](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/434#issuecomment-352341311))

I would also recommend reading the following [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/11/28/intellij-idea-scala-plugin-2017-3-lightbend-project-starter-ammonite-support-parallel-indexing-and-more/) (scroll down to **Ammonite scripts support**) to make sure you have all needed requirements

Comment: Thanks but I already did that: 'I also specified that Scala worksheet files should be treated as "Always Ammonite".' Also, in the question, I linked to the blog post you mentioned. Also, in the solution you link to, I commented there a few days ago :)